How to map JSON in dropdown list
I want to map JSON when Level include some level then school include some schools but in one level not include any school and the program each level include program how to map and display data in dropdown or how to write condition.
JSON :
const programList :{
    level : [
            {levelName:"UG",school:[{schoolName:"XYZ",program : [{programName:"PQR"}]}]},
            {levelName:"PG",school:[{schoolName:"XYZ",program : [{programName:"PQR"}]}]},
            {levelName:"PHD",program : [{programName:"PQR"}]},
        ]
}

how to map JSON in dropdown when in the PHD level not include school
   How to map JSON data when Level--> PG,UG,PHD,DIPLOMA ,School-->include school in PG,UG,DIPLOMA but in PHD not include schools ,Program--> each level include programs how map this json


Can you show an example of the result you want? What would be the value and display name in the dropdown?

This appears to be a Javascript Object, not JSON; JSON is a string.

here is the image link https://i.imgur.com/Lvr0bVk.png refer this link for understanding

The image doesn't show how you want this to work. We need more context; please provide a [mre].
